# code to reverse any given string in python using basic python operators

Tags: python

I am new to programming. I am trying to write a code to print the reverse of any given string.
I have written the following code:

```
import math
string= raw_input ("Enter string")
n= len(string)
ol= n-1
for ol>-1,ol--:
    print string[ol]
```

but i am getting syntax error. Please help me to figure this out.

Comment: `for ol>-1,ol--`, that's not python syntax.

Comment: Why do you need math module?

Comment: @badc0re I said i am new to programming. So i just tried importing it to check if it would work out for me.

Comment: People downvoting this question: You were once beginners as well and stumped by similar problems, unable to think yourself out.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i did not know that. Its the only reason why i posted this question.

Comment: Right maybe you are a beginner, but have you tried reading about basics of python?

Comment: @badc0re At least i tried. Anyways will take care next time.

Comment: Yes you are right, try and don't give up. :)

Comment: OP was trying to do some sort of C-ish for-loop syntax. It's a pretty valid first guess for someone who hasn't done any python at all

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a lack of basic kwoledge of the sintaxis of python for loops from a beginner. Too localized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Python tries very hard to present code in a readable way](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PythonPhilosophy). This means you don't get many of the ugly, hard to understand shortcuts that other languages like C offer. Instead, you get other, much easier to understand shortcuts.

The code to loop over a range in python is:

```
for ol in range(n):
```

To iterate backwards, use

```
for ol in range(n-1,-1,-1):
```

But of course, someone couldn't resist and add an unreadable shortcut to the language:

```
print string[::-1]
```

Related:

- [Loop backwards using indices in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869885/loop-backwards-using-indices-in-python)
- [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)

Comment: It worked for me and thanks for the references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these links for your further work, i know that this answer is out of the topic:

[Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/)

> People all over the world are learning with Codecademy.

[Python the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

> Learn Python The Hard Way, 3rd Edition

[Python Monk](http://pythonmonk.com/)

> Free, interactive tutorials to help you discover Python idioms, in
>   your browser!

Comment: Thank you for the references you provided. Will definitely go through it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code the string reverse yourself, try this as well. This will be useful when you reverse a very large string. You just have to **traverse only half of it**.

```
Data = list("ABCDEF")
Len  = len(Data)

for i in range(Len//2):
    Data[i], Data[Len - i - 1] = Data[Len - i - 1], Data[i]

Data = ''.join(Data)

print Data
```

**NOTE:** This solution is just for learning. For practical purposes, use @Aaron Digulla's third option. It will give far better performance than anything else. Its called slicing. Read about it here http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

```
print string[::-1]
```